# SQL Statement giving error

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I am using SQLite on Android and am getting a problem when running this command :

```
UPDATE vocab_words SET correct = 5 
WHERE
    name = 'AQA GCSE Spanish Higher',
    foreign_word = 'campo, el',
    english_meaning = 'field, the'
```

What is the problem here? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: wats the prob put stack trace

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn Please use [proper grammar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129729/188646) as [Writing Style Matters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your SQL query has a syntax error.Change your query from:

```
UPDATE vocab_words SET correct = 5 WHERE name = 'AQA GCSE Spanish Higher', foreign_word = 'campo, el', english_meaning = 'field, the'
```

to:

```
UPDATE vocab_words SET correct = 5 WHERE name = 'AQA GCSE Spanish Higher'AND foreign_word = 'campo, el'AND english_meaning = 'field, the'
```

Also I suggest you to read basics of SQL using some tutorials. This is one of the basic error.

Answer (score 3):

*Combine two or more simple conditions by using the `AND` not with `comma(,)`.*

> UPDATE vocab_words SET correct = 5 WHERE name = 'AQA GCSE Spanish
>   Higher', foreign_word = 'campo, el', english_meaning = 'field, the'

Replace with

> UPDATE vocab_words SET correct = 5 WHERE name = 'AQA GCSE Spanish
>   Higher' AND foreign_word = 'campo, el' AND english_meaning = 'field, the'

Answer (score 0):

From initial viewing your post the update statement should be -

```
UPDATE vocab_words SET correct = 5 WHERE name = 'AQA GCSE Spanish Higher' and foreign_word = 'campo, el' and english_meaning = 'field, the'
```